# Removing .html file extension from URL with an .htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried a number of different snippets inside my .htaccess file in order to remove the .html file extension from displaying in the URL.  So far I've read some other answers on here that haven't worked, researched some personal blogs, and even found some tricks that didn't work on Chris Coyier's CSS Tricks.

Here's a couple of the ones I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

As well as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```